# Creating a Barrier for multi-thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I am doing the Barrier task from mits081([link](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2020/labs/thread.html))

The thing to do is to implement the function barrier to stop threads from moving forward until all threads have reached.
my implementation sometimes fail and sometimes succeed, so I print out some info inside the barrier function to help debug   `printf("%d :%d\n", bstate.nthread, syscall(__NR_gettid));`
when succeed,  the output will be like

```
0 :81906
0 :81907
0 :81907
0 :81906
0 :81906
1 :81907
0 :81906
1 :81907
0 :81906
0 :81907
0 :81907
0 :81906
0 :81907
0 :81906
0 :81906
1 :81907
0 :81907
0 :81906
0 :81906
1 :81907
OK; passed
```

when fail, it will stuck after printing the last line as shown.

```
0 :81909
0 :81910
0 :81910
1 :81909
0 :81910
0 :81909
0 :81909
0 :81910
0 :81909
1 :81910
0 :81910
1 :81909
0 :81909
1 :81910
0 :81910
1 :81909
0 :81909
1 :81910
0 :81910
1 :81909
```

Could someone kindly tell me what's wrong with my implementation? Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
static int nthread = 1;
static int round = 0;

struct barrier
{
  pthread_mutex_t barrier_mutex;
  pthread_cond_t barrier_cond;
  int nthread; // Number of threads that have reached this round of the barrier
  int round;   // Barrier round
} bstate;

static void
barrier_init(void)
{
  assert(pthread_mutex_init(&bstate.barrier_mutex, NULL) == 0);
  assert(pthread_cond_init(&bstate.barrier_cond, NULL) == 0);
  bstate.nthread = 0;
}

static void
barrier()
{
  // YOUR CODE HERE
  //
  // Block until all threads have called barrier() and
  // then increment bstate.round.
  // //
  printf("%d :%d\n", bstate.nthread, syscall(__NR_gettid));

  if (++bstate.nthread % nthread == 0)
  {
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&bstate.barrier_cond); // wake up every thread sleeping on cond
    bstate.round++;

  }
  else
    pthread_cond_wait(&bstate.barrier_cond, &bstate.barrier_mutex); // go to sleep on cond, releasing lock mutex, acquiring upon wake up
}

static void *
thread(void *xa)
{
  long n = (long)xa;
  long delay;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    int t = bstate.round;
    assert(i == t);
    barrier();
    usleep(random() % 100);
  }
  // printf("a");

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t *tha;
  void *value;
  long i;
  double t1, t0;

  if (argc < 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s nthread\n", argv[0], argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
  }
  nthread = atoi(argv[1]);
  tha = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * nthread);
  srandom(0);

  barrier_init();

  for (i = 0; i < nthread; i++)
  {
    assert(pthread_create(&tha[i], NULL, thread, (void *)i) == 0);
      printf("%d\n", syscall(__NR_gettid));
  }
    

  for (i = 0; i < nthread; i++)
  {

    assert(pthread_join(tha[i], &value) == 0);
  }
  printf("OK; passed\n");
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to implement this yourself rather than just use what standard, modern C++ provides you?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean [C] instead of [C++] ?

Comment: sorry my bad, it is c. I will update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *all* access to variables that you read/write from multiple threads simultaneously to be synchronized. You currently don't lock the mutex in `barrier()` which causes a race condition and *undefined behavior*. Your `pthread_cond_wait` may also wake up because of spurious wake-ups so you need to check the condition (that it's time to start the next round) every time it wakes up.

Example fix:

```c
static void barrier() {
    // lock the mutex:
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bstate.barrier_mutex);

    printf("%d :%ld\n", ++bstate.nthread, syscall(__NR_gettid));

    if(bstate.nthread == nthread) {
        // wake up every thread sleeping on cond
        printf("round %d done\n", bstate.round++);
        bstate.nthread = 0;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&bstate.barrier_cond);
    } else {
        int lround = bstate.round;
        // sleep until the next round starts:
        do {
            pthread_cond_wait(&bstate.barrier_cond, &bstate.barrier_mutex);
        } while(lround == bstate.round);
    }

    // unlock the mutex:
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bstate.barrier_mutex);
}
```

Also note that your `thread` function also reads from a variable (`bstate.round`) without synchronization which is also written to by other threads. Remove that:

```c
static void* thread(void* xa) {
    long n = (long)xa;
    long delay;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        barrier();
        usleep(random() % 100);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations which really help!!! but I don't understand where the spurious wake-ups come from or what causes this. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @oo You're welcome! Where the spurious wakeups come from isn't well described in [`pthread_cond_wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) - but they do happen in real life so one must always be prepared to deal with them.